# Swiper Element doesn't swipe

Tags: javascript, reactjs, swiper.js

I am using swiper elements, just as explained here:
https://swiperjs.com/element

The weird thing is, if I swipe, the navigation shows the next page but the content from the first page is still shown. The CSS attribute even changes to swiper-slide-active.

My setup is so simple that I can't imagine the mistake. And I couldn't find any help online.

If anyone wonders. the mapping I do of the event works. it has two objects and in the dom, I see that the slides actually contain the element's content.

I tried changing the slideContent's CSS properties, but that doesn't seem to be the problem.

**Edit:** Only the Html and CSS part should be enough to find the problem.

---

Here is the code:

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { getFutureMeditations } from '../Helpers/RestCalls';
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';
import '../CSS/Home.css';
import tree from '../images/tree.webp';

// import function to register Swiper custom elements
import { register } from 'swiper/element/bundle';
// register Swiper custom elements
register();

function Home() {
    const swiperElRef = useRef(null);
    // Now you can use Swiper
    const [events, setEvents] = useState([]);
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    useEffect(() => {
        //swiper configuration
        swiperElRef.current.addEventListener('progress', (e) => {
            const [swiper, progress] = e.detail;
            console.log(progress);
        });

        swiperElRef.current.addEventListener('slidechange', (e) => {
            console.log('slide changed');
        });

        getFutureMeditations().then((result) => {
            setEvents(result);
            console.log(result);
        });
        //Refresh Future Meditations every 10 seconds
        setInterval(() => {
            getFutureMeditations().then((result) => {
                setEvents(result);
                console.log(result);
            });
        }, 10000);
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className='homeScreen'>
            <swiper-container ref={swiperElRef} navigation='true' pagination='true'>
                {events.map((event) => {
                    return (
                        <swiper-slide>
                            <div className='slideContent'>
                                <h5>{event.title}</h5>
                                <p>{event.description}</p>
                                <p>
                                    {event.date.substring(0, 10) +
                                        ' - ' +
                                        event.date.substring(11, 16)}
                                </p>
                                <a
                                    onClick={() => navigate('room/' + event._id)}
                                    className='btn'
                                >
                                    Go to Room
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </swiper-slide>
                    );
                })}
            </swiper-container>

            {/* <img src={tree} alt='tree' /> */}
            <div className='templeTitle'>Tempel</div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Home;
```

***style.css***

```
body {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.homeScreen {
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
}
.slideContent {
    background-color: green;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.templeTitle {
    color: black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    right: 100px;
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

Comment: I apologize in advance but cannot resist: swiper no swiping?